# Django + ndb/GAE: can't figure out how to properly display results from queries

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm on a Google App Engine application, and I'm using django for views, templates, and file structure, and ndb for models/queries/dealing with the datastore.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to properly display a model via a query. It seems like I'm able to post to the datastore and retrieve from it alright, but I can't print what I've retrieved. I get back a StringProperty() object, which I think the Django request handler can't decipher, so it literally just prints "StringProperty()". Either that, or I just don't understand ndb queries as well as I think :)

Anyway, any ideas as to how I can make it show up correctly? Am I doomed for trying to combine ndb and django like this?

How it shows up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kERoQ.jpg

In models.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

# Create your models here.
class Contact(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty
    address_street = ndb.StringProperty
    address_extra = ndb.StringProperty
    address_city = ndb.StringProperty
    address_state = ndb.StringProperty
    address_zipcode = ndb.StringProperty
    email = ndb.StringProperty
    phone = ndb.StringProperty
```

In views.py:

```
from django import http 
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models import Contact

def home(request):
    contacts = Contact.query().fetch()

    return render_to_response('index.html', {'message':'Hello World', 'contacts':contacts})

def form(request):
    c = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact = Contact()
        contact.name = request.POST['name']
        address_street = request.POST['street']
        address_extra = request.POST['extra']
        address_city = request.POST['city']
        address_state = request.POST['state']
        address_zipcode = request.POST['zipcode']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        contact.put()

        return render_to_response('form.html', {'message':'Your contact, ' + contact.name + ', has been added.'}, c)
    else:
        return render_to_response('form.html', {'message':'Form!'}, c)
```

In index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block pagestyle %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ message }}
    <br><br>

    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Address</td><td>City</td><td>State</td><td>Zipcode</td><td>Email</td><td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
    {% for contact in contacts %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <div class="button" value="/form">Add a contact</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You model definition is incorrect. You are not creating properties, just holding references to the Property class, it should be

```
class Contact(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    address_street = ndb.StringProperty()
    address_extra = ndb.StringProperty()
    address_city = ndb.StringProperty()
    address_state = ndb.StringProperty()
    address_zipcode = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    phone = ndb.StringProperty()
```

And thats why you are seeing StringProperty in the output.

Comment: Man, all my errors have just been dumb on this project. But I'm relieved it was just a silly mistake. Thanks so much.